# does Location Client fetches Data from Google Map???

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

I am fetching Locations using Location client.

Sometimes I am getting locations 20 mins before and at same time i see that google maps also showing same location as returned by location client.

This is giving me a feeling that it fetches data from google maps.

So am i correct???